# Retrieving HashSet<string> object reference

Tags: .net-3.5, hashset

How can I efficiently get a reference to a string in a `HashSet<string>` if I know the string exists?

i.e.

```
hashSet.Contains(myString) == true
string stringRef = ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I basically want to do dynamic string interning.

Comment: You mean you want to grab a reference so you can mutate it? Aren't `string`s immutable? And if you can't mutate it, why don't you just remove the old one and add the new one?

Comment: And if `strings` aren't immutable, mutating the string will likely cause the `HashSet` to "lose" it (i.e. it will appear when you iterate through the set but you won't be able to find it with `Contains()` again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx